# Is there "Save as" option in Android Studio file menu?

Tags: android, android-studio, save-as

I have recently move from Eclipse to Android Studio. I could not find "File > Save as" options. Is there any alternative for this?

(Sometimes, I create new class or XML by creating new one from already existed content, and than do changes. In Eclipise I have been doing this by using "Save as" options from File menu)

Comment: Android studio will save automatically. AFAIK, "save as" is not an option because it will save to where it currently resides.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest solution which I've used multiple times would be:

- Right click on the original file in project hierarchy panel.
- Choose `Refactor`
- Choose `Copy`
- Enter `New Name` and `Destination Package`

Shortcut: <kbd>F5</kbd>